# TreeMap<Object,Object> issue

Tags: java

How can I have a key object and value object MapTree?

```
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class ClassA {
    Integer phoneNumber;
    ClassA(Integer noKey){
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }



public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<ClassA, ClassB> map = new TreeMap<> ();

    ClassB bob = new ClassB ("bob", "jamaica", 1234567890);
    
    map.put (?????,bob);
}

class ClassB {
    String name, adress;
    Integer phoneNumber;

ClassB(String name, String adress, Integer phoneNumber){
    this.name = name;
    this.adress = adress;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}
```

How to put same phoneNumber from classB to key TreeMap witch it in ClassA? I do not want to make too many change of the construction of my code. I need this in two separate classes.

Comment: my java skill (LOW), and in ClassA should be phoneNumber in constructor....

Comment: It's a good idea to spell the natural-language parts of identifiers with conventional natural-language spelling, thus `address` rather than `adress`. This builds the habit of creating maintainable code.

Comment: If you read the Javadocs for `Map#put`, you'll see that the first argument is a reference to an instance of the key type, in your case `ClassA`. So build an instance of that key type and use it as the key in the `put` call.

Comment: @LewBloch thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't quite understand java yet. First off, you're using `Integer` instead of `int` which well, should be fine but it'll cause problems later.

Next to that, ClassA's constructor is just a bit off. You're assigning the value of `phoneNumber` to itself instead of the integer parsed.

You should change it to this:

```
class ClassA {
    int phoneNumber;
    public ClassA (int newPhoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = newPhoneNumber;
    }
}
```

This will assign the value of phoneNumber to the one given to the class, instead to itself.

Then, to create an instance of ClassA with the same phone number as ClassB, you could simply do it like this:

```
ClassB bob = new ClassB ("bob", "jamaica", 1234567890);

ClassA phone = new ClassA (bob.phoneNumber);

map.put (phone, bob);
```

I hope I was of help.

Comment: thx Man, have a nice day/evening :)

Comment: Use of `Integer` instead of `int` will not cause any problems later, though arguably `String` would have been a better choice to represent a phone number.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to change `TreeMap<ClassA, ClassB>` to a `TreeMap<Integer, ClassB>`, and pass the phone number instead of an instance of `ClassA` to `put` and `get` methods. This takes advantage of the fact that `Integer` already has a natural ordering (i.e. it implements `Comparable<Integer>`).

Another way is to change `ClassA` to implement `Comparable<ClassA>`, so that two `ClassA` instances having the same phone number will be considered identical by the `TreeMap`.

A third way is to pass a `Comparator<ClassA>` to the constructor of `TreeMap`. This `Comparator` will compare the phone numbers of two `ClassA` instances.

For example:

```
public class ClassAComparator implements Comparator<ClassA>
{
    public int compare (ClassA one, ClassB two) {
        return Integer.compare(one.getPhoneNumber(),two.getPhoneNumber());
    }
}
```

and then:

```
TreeMap<ClassA, ClassB> map = new TreeMap<> (new ClassAComparator ());
```

Comment: I am clearly not understanding the question correctly, but couldn't we do something like `map.put (new ClassA(bob.getPhoneNumber()),bob);` by adding a getter in `classB` ?

Comment: 1st i knew it, but i need two objects.
3rd i dont get it... can you describe it ?

Comment: @Shashwat that's not enough if ClassA doesn't implement `Comparable<ClassA>`.

Comment: @theHabuUser see edit

Comment: Ye but @086 make it how i want to :) but thx for ur time :)

Comment: @theHabuUser Well, that answer indeed covered a few of your mistakes, but not all of them. After you run that code and get an exception, you can look into my answer.